# How do I smooth or sculpt eye sculpt? (stylized character)

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, sculpting, geometry

I've been working on my character following this video: (I'm stuck at 16:24)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLWGfbkAb54&t=877s&ab_channel=Dikko
When he does it the result is smooth (16:34)
When I try to do it I can't seem to smooth my mesh-like he does. I followed everything he said to do. I Ctrl j to join the head mesh I model with the eyelid mesh I model, then in sculpt mode, all I did was use smooth and grab tool. Everything was fine until I used the clay strip. I would get these folds and creases that would not smooth out but deepens not matter how much clay I add and smooth out.
This is what mine looks like which I can't seem to figure out how to fix to match his.[[image: See the circled area?][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLhao.jpg).
[image: No matter how I try to fix it I just make it worst :(]
[image: This is the mesh in edit mode]
[image: This is how it's supposed to look screen grabbed from the youtube video... can someone tell me how to fix this issue? I didn't do any texturing. The head does have mirroring and subdivision and the eye lid has mirror, subdivsion and solidifier. It's all modeling and sculpting nothing else. Pls help!!!]

Comment: That is an awfully lot of topology. Unfortunately, I can't help you with 2.90 as I am not sufficiently up-to-date with that version or beyond. Some hotkeys are changed — initially, that confused me, as I was long used to the old ones like those for smoothening mesh and merging vertrices. You can google for cheat sheet for Blender 2.90 hotkeys.